# Multiple Web Apps in Azure's Basic Tier

Tags: azure

I'm new to Azure, and a stronger developer than a network guy.  I have read that you can host multiple websites/domains in each Basic plan.

I choose the B1 Basic plan for one of my web apps and it is deployed. I have others currently under the free option, all in the same resource group.

Do I just upgrade the others to B1 Basic, and it will treat them as one financially?

When reading online I see references to VMs and instances...which confuse me.  So I'm not sure if its more complicated than that, requiring additional components and/or configuration?

A thorough explanation would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of Web Apps, or any other app that's part of App Service, is tied to something called App Service Plans. Apps are always associated with one App Service Plan and you are billed for the App Service Plans in your subscription, e.g. you will be billed for the same amount regardless if you have one Web App in a Free tier App Service Plan and one Web App in a Basic tier or if the Basic tier App Service Plan contained 10 Web Apps.

The number of apps you can host within an App Service Plan depends on your requirements and the pricing tier, see the documentation for [subscription limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits---web-apps-mobile-apps-api-apps-logic-apps).

Apps can also be freely moved between App Service Plans, so if your apps need to the use the features offered in the Basic tier you can [move them](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview) into a Basic tier App Service Plan.